# Change Vue root instance data value on component's button click, then change another component's v-show/v-if

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-reactivity

So I've been struggling with this issue for the whole of yesterday. Basically I have a root component with a data property **dbEnabled** that should decide whether to display another child component named **Database**.

This should be achieved by pressing a button on yet another child component named **Navigation**. I managed to send this property from root to component by defining it as a prop on the receiving component and passing to **v-show** or **v-if** of **Database**. Unfortunately, it only reacts upon creation of the instance (doesn't react to change).

So far I've managed to achieve this another way by using **document.getElementByID(#db)** and adding a class that sets **display: none !important;** for this element but can it be done with Vue natively?

This is the main.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import Title from './Components/Title.vue'
import Navigation from './Components/Navigation.vue'
import AddProduct from './Components/AddProduct.vue'
import Database from './Components/Database.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.component('app-title', Title)
Vue.component('nav-buttons', Navigation)
Vue.component('add-product', AddProduct)
Vue.component('db', Database)

/* eslint-disable no-new */
window.App = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { App, Title, Navigation, AddProduct, Database },
  template: '<App/>',
  data: {
    dbEnabled: false // <-- this should decide whether to show/hide #db element
  }
})
```

This is the navigation component that contains the toggling button:

```
<template>
  <div id="nav-div">
    <button> {{ planBtn }}</button>
    <button> {{ addBtn }}</button>
    <button> {{ editBtn }}</button>
    <button @click="hideDb()"> {{ dbBtn }}</button> //<--here I tried openDb() function    
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Navigation',
    props: ['dbEnabled'],
    data() {
      return {
        dbBtn: 'Open database',
        addBtn: 'Add product',
        planBtn: 'Plan meal',
        editBtn: 'Edit product'
      }
    },

    methods: {
      openDb() {
        App.dbEnabled = !App.dbEnabled //<--This function changes the root instance's 
                                       //value but the v-show/v-if doesn't react to the 
                                       //change. Nor does changing this value in Chrome
                                       //console make it react
      },

      hideDb() {
        let d = document.getElementById("db")
        d.className = (d.className === '') ? db.className='db-hidden' : db.className=''
        }
      }
    }

</script>
```

This is the Database component:

```
<template>
  <div id="db"> //<--Tried v-show/v-if here, but works only initially
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th
            v-for="prAttr in gridColumns"
          >{{ prAttr }}</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr
          :weight="weight"
          v-for="product in products">
          <td> {{ product.name }}  </td>
          <td> {{ carbs(product, weight) }} </td>
          <td> {{ sugar(product, weight) }} </td>
          <td> {{ fiber(product, weight) }} </td>
          <td> {{ fat(product, weight) }} </td>
          <td> {{ protein(product, weight) }} </td>
          <td> {{ unknwn(product, weight) }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Database',

    data() {
      return {
        weight: 100,
        gridColumns: ['Product name', 'Carbs (%)', 'Sugar (%)', 'Fiber (%)',
        'Fat (%)', 'Protein (%)', 'Unknwn(%)'],
        products: [
          {name: 'Rimi piens pasterizets 2,5%', carbs: 4.8, sugar: 4.8,
        fiber: 0, fat: 2.5, protein: 3.2, unknwn: 'unknwn_ingredients'},
          {name: 'Santini Ksylitol', carbs: 99.8, sugar: 0.2,
        fiber: 0, fat: 0, protein: 0}
        ]
      }
    },

    props: ['dbEnabled'],

    methods: {
      unknwn(cp, weight) {
        let unknwn_ingredients = (100 - cp.carbs
         - cp.fiber - cp.fat - cp.protein) / weight * 100
        return unknwn_ingredients.toFixed(2)
        },

      carbs(cp, weight) {
        let carbs = cp.carbs / weight * 100
        return carbs
      },

      sugar(cp, weight) {
        let sugar = cp.carbs / weight * 100
        return sugar
      },

      fiber(cp, weight) {
        let fiber = cp.carbs / weight * 100
        return fiber
      },

      fat(cp, weight) {
        let fat = cp.carbs / weight * 100
        return fat
      },

      protein(cp, weight) {
        let protein = cp.carbs / weight * 100
        return protein
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are targeting the wrong place. You want to target the [root component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-the-Root-Instance), not the actual vue instance(App)

The simplest way to fix this would be to change `App.dbEnabled = !App.dbEnabled` to `this.$root.dbEnabled = !this.$root.dbEnabled`

Do you have [vue-devtools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools#vue-devtools) installed? This helps alot to see what you are actually targeting.

I would also advice you to look at [vm.$emit()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit).
Personally, I would use emit to push child changes upward the chain. However, in your example, this might be a bit overkill.

Comment: Yes, I have vue-devtools installed. In it shows that the root component is $vm0. Funny thing is that when I refresh the app and type $vm0 in console - it shows `Uncaught ReferenceError: $vm0 is not defined.

`this.$root` outputs as `undefined`.

I tried replacing `App.dbEnabled` with `this.$root.dbEnabled` and it **does** change the value of the property, however `v-shot` and `v-if` still doesn't react to change of the boolean value. What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, this is normal :) vue-devtools sets the $vm0 on click and it does not remember on reload :/

Comment: Curiously, after opening vue-devtools, typing `$vm0.dbEnabled = true` makes the component react. But I cannot use this to refer to the root instance in code.

Comment: No, that is correct. $vm0 is just a temporary variable pointing to your selected component, provided by vue-devtools. This means it is only available to you in dev mode and if you initializes it via dev-tools. You cannot use this in side your code because it does not exist

Comment: As I wrote in the answer, what you have to do is to change `App.dbEnabled = !App.dbEnabled` in Navigation.vue to `this.$root.dbEnabled = !this.$root.dbEnabled`. "this.$root" can be broken down to; `this` refers to the components vue instance. This is the same as you clicking the root component in dev-tools.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Now what if I wanted to refer to data property of another component (sibling or otherwise)?

I tried to do this: `this.$emit('some-info')` on a component and then `v-on:some-info="console.log('test')"` on a different component's element but it didn't work.

Comment: It's worth noting that the component only reacted when I changed `v-show` from the prop `dbEnabled` (didn't react to it) to `this.$root.dbEnabled`.

That means that props are useless to monitor root instance data. :(

Comment: You have to pass a prop down. where you initialized navigation component, you have to have dbEnabled in its data. ( `<Navigation :dbEnabled="dbEnabled" /> ` ) [Passing-Data](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props)

Comment: Would be nice if you accepted the answer :) @askepott